# Pascal's Triangle program not working

Tags: c

I'm very new to C, although I've done a decent amount of Java before. I'm making a basic Pascal's Triangle program and I've been looking at it for an hour trying to get it working. All the logic seems correct to me but I'll probably die before I realize what's wrong. Here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
double fact(int num);

int main()
{
    int row_index = 0;
    printf("Enter the row index : ");
    scanf("%d",&row_index);
    printf("\n");
    int i;
    double output1 = 0;
    double output2 = 0;
    double output3 = 0;
    double output4 = 0;
    double output5 = 0;
    int output6 = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= (row_index + 1); i++)
    {
        output1 = fact(row_index);
        output2 = fact(i);
        output3 = row_index - i;
        output4 = fact(output3);
        output5 = output1 / (output2 * output4);
        output6 = (int)(output5);
        printf("%i ",output6);
    }
    return 0;
}

double fact(int num)
{
    double result;
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
        {
            result = result * i;
        }
    return result;
}
```

The compiler is giving me no errors, and each every time I input a number it gives this as output:

```
Enter the row index : 6

-2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648
```

Comment: Numbers are less likely to go out of range if you can find a progressive algorithm which multiplies and divides a previous term, instead of trying to shoot the moon with a factorial function. Or, which builds an array by addition only of two previous array terms.

Answer (score 0):

In `double fact(int num)`, the variable `result` should be explicitly initialized. Also, I would suggest you to define both the return value of the function and variable `result` to `int` type.

See [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c).

Comment: 32-bit `int` will only be able to hold results up to 12!.

Comment: At least use `uint64_t`

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, there seems to be several issues.

First:

```
double fact(int num)
{
    double result;
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
    {
    result = result * i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

result is not initialized to anything. Maybe you need to initialize it to 1?

```
for(i = 0; i <= (row_index + 1); i++)
{
    output2 = fact(i);
    output3 = row_index - i;
    output4 = fact(output3);
    output5 = output1 / (output2 * output4);
}
```

the first time around, i == 0; which means output2 at best will be 0 (assuming its automatically initialized to 0).  If output2 == 0, output5 might be undefined.  I say might because of double-precision numbers it may actually not be exactly 0.